# What is the best measure for the world's economic cycle?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, business-cycles, purchasing-power-partity, real-business-cycles

I'm trying to make a graph that shows how the return of major assets (S&P 500 index, % of 3Y T-notes, oil, gold, etc) move along with the world's expansion& recession cycle.

I looked into [World Bank website](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD?locations=OE) but I'm not sure which measure I should use to represent the world's real business cycle.

FYI, you can select different GDP/PPP measures on the right pane.

Here are my questions:

1. Should I use World data vs OECD data?

OECD countries take up the most part of the world's finance. Is using OECD good enough / more accurate?

2. I think I should use GDP growth rate. But does it represent real, not nominal data?

I should use *real* GDP, right? But as you can see, the website only has [one growth rate graph](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?locations=OE). So does that mean I have to make my own graph by downloading real GDP?

3. There are GDP and PPP. Which one should I use?

What I want to do is showing the relationship of each asset's return with the world's economy. Since GDP is represented in USD, should I use PPP instead if I want to capture real economy without the effect of exchange rate?

Comment: There’s probably a report or webpage that details the methodology behind the website charts. It would answer most of your questions.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk Right, but what I want to know is whether the data in my project (where I compare world GDP & many other financial assets to see the relationship) is appropriate.

Comment: You want world real GDP? Validate which series matches that by looking at the other sources of data from the source. You should do that yourself, rather than rely on random people on the internet to read documentation for you.